# Code To block a port for a process in C++, Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, winsock

I'm developing a windows Firewall as my Final Year Project. For this I want to block port for processes in c++. Which API should be used to do this, or if there's any KERNEL MODE API which can be overridden like `PsSetCreateNrocessNotifyRoutine`?

Comment: might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876701/is-there-a-windows-socket-api-call-option-to-block-a-range-of-ports-a-la-so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows Vista and later, you should be using the [Windows Filtering Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366510.aspx), which is accessible from both user-mode and kernel-mode. See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29026/Firewall-using-Vista-s-Windows-Filtering-Platform) for an example.

Comment: @above , Sir i really appreciate your concern and its really helpful kindly tell  ,do you need WDK or any driver kid to run Windows filtering platfom API or code, thanks